# Reference or idea of a proof (on A-groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

There is the following result on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=A-group&action=edit&section=3):

> The Fitting subgroup of a solvable $A$-group is equal to the direct product of the centers of the terms of the derived series.

An $A$-group is a (finite) group whose all Sylow subgroup are abelian. The proof of this result can be found on Huppert 1967. Unfortunally I don't have access to the book and I cannot read German.

So, does anyone know another reference or how to prove?

Comment: There are English editions, see [here](https://books.google.at/books/about/Finite_Groups.html?id=dfSguAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Wait, has Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I been translated?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It seems to be the vol II. The proof I look for seems not to be in vol II or vol III.

Comment: I believe that there is an English translation of this result, but if not, you can copy  the proof in German into this post and I will help translating it for you. Mostly there are symbols and not so many words. By the way, do you know [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4304265/let-g-be-a-finite-solvable-group-all-of-whose-sylow-subgroup-are-abelian-show?rq=1)?

Comment: By the way, reading group theory in German is pretty easy, you do not need to know that many words. I only know a few words of German, but I find the fraktur font to be more of an obstacle in Huppert's book!

Comment: @spin The problem is that you need to know aspects of German grammar that are not typically covered in a first course in German, such as the subjunctive. "Sei $G$ eine Gruppe. Dann ist ..." And I also have difficulty distinguishing between letters in the fraktur font!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Derek and spin! I will check a copy in German btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proof, based on Huppert.

First recall that by transfer, you can prove that if $P$ is an abelian $p$-Sylow, then $G' \cap P \cap Z(N_G(P)) = 1$. Thus if $G$ is a finite $A$-group, then $G' \cap Z(G) = 1$.

Now suppose that $G$ is a finite solvable group.

Let $p_1$, $\ldots$, $p_t$ be the prime divisors of $|G|$. Because $G$ is solvable,  it admits a Sylow system, meaning $P_i \in Syl_{p_i}(G)$ such that $P_iP_j = P_jP_i$ for all $j,i$. Denote $D = \cap_{i = 1}^t N_G(P_i)$.

> Lemma 1: Let $N \trianglelefteq G$. Then $N = (N \cap G')(N \cap D)$.

Proof: The image of $N$ is central in $G/N \cap G'$, so it normalizes the images of $P_i$. Thus $N \leq (N \cap G')D$, and by Dedekind's lemma $N = (N \cap G')(N \cap D)$. $\blacksquare$

> Lemma 2: Suppose that $G$ is an $A$-group and $N \trianglelefteq G$ is abelian. Then $N = (N \cap G') \times (N \cap Z(G))$.

Proof: It suffices to consider the case where $N$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p = p_i$.

By Lemma 1 we have $N = (N \cap G')(N \cap D)$. Also $G' \cap Z(G) = 1$ since $G$ is an $A$-group, so it suffices to check that $N \cap D \leq Z(G)$.

Since $N \leq P_i$ and $P_i$ is abelian, we have $[N \cap D,P_i] = 1$. Now $Q = \prod_{j \neq i} P_j$ is a subgroup of $G$ normalized by $D$, so $[N \cap D, Q] \leq Q \cap N = 1$. By $G = P_iQ$ we conclude $N \cap D \leq Z(G)$.$\blacksquare$

> Lemma 3: Suppose that $G$ is an $A$-group and $N \trianglelefteq G$ is abelian. Then $N = (N \cap Z(G)) \times (N \cap Z(G')) \times (N \cap Z(G'')) \times \cdots$

Proof: Apply Lemma 2 and induction on the length of the derived series of $G$. $\blacksquare$

As a corollary of Lemma 3, you get the desired result.

> If $G$ is an $A$-group, then $F(G) = Z(G) \times Z(G') \times Z(G'') \times \cdots$

Answer (score 4):

The proofs use the theory of system normalizers in solvable groups.

These results were proved originally in

D. Taunt, On $A$-groups, Cambridge Phil. Soc. 45, 14-42, 1949,

which is in English.